# Is there an easy way to remove a URL from Safari's address bar history?

Tags: safari, bookmarks, browser-history

So, I love the new, awesomebar-style address bar in Safari 5 - with it's history search, I've gotten to the point where I no longer use bookmarks for most sites, I just remember the 2-4 letter strings that will bring what I want to the top of the search results.

This is great, except for when I screw up and add things to the history that screw with it. For example, one of my most used shortcuts was to get to a site I frequent by typing "bl" and hitting enter. Somehow, at one point, I did this without a search coming up, and now, the "Top Hit" for "bl" is "http://bl/", which is obviously, not an actual site.

Is there any way to remove a single entry from the history without clearing the history entirely?

**Bonus points if it can be done from the address bar without navigating around in prefs or anything.** While the answers currently given work, I'd love to find an *easier* way to do it.

Comment: +1 Would love to find a fix for this - especially when clearing the history does nothing to resolve it. (Just shows as "Top Hit").

Comment: Just came to the site to ask the exact same question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

click on show all bookmark (open book) on top-left of your safari. then search the site you want to remove (e.g: http://bl) after that delete it from history when you delete the singe site you never find http://bl when press bl in address bar.

[image]

search here:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, going to leave this open for a day or so to see if there's a faster way to do this on the fly from the address bar though. Thanks!

Comment: It's fast enough I think :P and also your welcome.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Does this fix it for you?

Comment: @less if you don't want to click, you can always use `Opt+Cmd+2` to access History

Comment: @Chealion: Yes it does.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Good to hear.

Comment: @LoïcWolff With Safari 8.0.6 I couldn't find history in the bookmarks as described above, but your keyboard combination shows a searchable list that includes favourites and history. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go in bookmarks menu and select show bookmarks, then search the url you want to delete with the search field on the top right (under the search engine bar), select the url to remove in the bottom part on hit delete key

Answer (score 1):

In **Safari 8** the accepted answer no longer seems to work as history isn't within the bookmarks any more. Instead, there are options in the `History` menu to show and edit history.

As pointed out in a [comment above by Loïc Wolff](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345/is-there-an-easy-way-to-remove-a-url-from-safaris-address-bar-history#comment316_346) you can use the keyboard combination `Opt+Cmd+2` to show history and a search field is available at the bottom right.